# Difference between Forwarded declaration and Include Header Files

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

What is the Difference between Forwarded declaration and Include Header files?

When I should use Forwarded Declaration and when I should use Header Files?

Because I got sometimes it is preferred to use Forwarded declaration and sometimes it is preferred to include the files.

Comment: My recommendation: use forward declaration *when possible*, otherwise include header.

Comment: Use forwarded declarations when possible.  Consider using header-header files (`*.hh`) which just provides the forward declarations of the associated header files (`*.h`).  Follow the *include what you use* rule, and never depend on indirect includes.

Comment: When you just need pointer, use forward declaration. When you need info from the type (method, field), include header.